# Hooking dll loaded to memory

Tags: c, winapi, dll, hook, ntdll

I'm trying to write a program, which will catch the event of a dll load into memory. 
For that purpose I put a hook on `LdrLoadDll` API. 
That works very fine, but the problem is that this API doesn't catch dlls which loaded as dependencies.
For example -

```
LoadLibraryW(L"C:\...\chrome_child.dll");
```

using `LdrLoadDl` I will catch `chrome_child.dll` loading to memory, but I won't catch `win32u.dll` which is one of `chrome_child.dll` dependencies.

Does anyone know a better API to use for that purpose?

Comment: you can use `LdrRegisterDllNotification` begin from vista - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347460(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks! It works, However this API was added only in Vista. Do you know about something that might work on Windows XP too?

Comment: for XP exist several **undocumented** options - we can use `LdrSetDllManifestProber` for set own callback, which will be called when dll loaded. but in callback we will be need yourself create activation context for dll (by `CreateActCtx` ) or find original callback  and use it. **note** `LdrSetDllManifestProber` signature changed in new windows versions (now it take 3 callbacks) but on `XP` it have only one param and this already never changed.

Comment: the most power option - call `LdrInitShimEngineDynamic(&__ImageBase)` in this case you need export several funcs - `SE_InstallBeforeInit`
`SE_InstallAfterInit`, `SE_DllLoaded`, `SE_DllUnloaded`, `SE_IsShimDll`, `SE_ProcessDying`, `SE_GetProcAddress`. this give you great control over dll load/unload process. ShimEngine is very volatile, and changed in every new windows version. however XP already will not changed

Comment: finally - you can hook `ZwMapViewOfSection` - and query it `SectionImageInformation`, also when dll loaded (but not data section mapped) `NT_TIB.ArbitraryUserPointer` point to full dll path

Comment: Thank you, it's really helpful! I want to use the `ZwMapViewOfSection` method, but I couldn't really understand where do I find the pointer to the full path of the dll?

Comment: in `NT_TIB.ArbitraryUserPointer` - this is point to unicode (PWSTR) path to image file

Comment: look `NtCurrentTeb()` macro in `winnt.h` and `NT_TIB` definition

Comment: in `winnt.h` look

Comment: look this - http://imgur.com/a/sOS41

Comment: Does it suppose to work the same in a 32 bit process? I didn't see the assignment you posted in Windbg in 32 bit process, and: `LoadLibraryExW(L"C:\\...\\chrome_child.dll", NULL, 0);
 PNT_TIB teb = (PNT_TIB)NtCurrentTeb(); teb2->ArbitraryUserPointer` points to 0X00000000. Is there a way to extract the path or the dll name from  SectionImageInformation?

Comment: yes, of course this true in both 32 and 64 bit processes. `ArbitraryUserPointer` point to path only when `ZwMapViewOfSection` called - just after this it restored to saved value

Comment: look better to http://imgur.com/a/sOS41 - `ArbitraryUserPointer` ([rdi+28h]) - assigned with path several instructions before `ZwMapViewOfSection` called and on next instruction after call already restored to saved value (`rbx`)

Comment: It seems like it worked, thank you!

Comment: this is from 32 bit process - look for `[edi+14]` - http://imgur.com/a/9hVOn

Comment: @RbMm None of these will intercept manually mapped images.